# Regex (or bash), get pipes between quotes (perl)

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, tr

Update: Please keep in mind is that regex is my only option.

Update 2: Actually, I can use a bash based solution as well.

Trying to replace the pipes(can be more than one) that are between double quotes with commas in perl regex

Example

```
continuer|"First, Name"|123|12412|10/21/2020|"3|7"||Yes|No|No|
```

Expected output (3 and 7 are separated by a comma)

```
continuer|"First, Name"|123|12412|10/21/2020|"3,7"||Yes|No|No|
```

There may be more digits, it may not be just the two `d\|d`. It could be `"3|7|2"` and the correct output has to be `"3,7,2"` for that one. I've tried the following

```
cat <filename> | perl -pi -e 's/"\d+\|[\|\d]+/\d+,[\|\d]+/g'
```

but it just puts the actual string of `d+` etc...

I'd really appreciate your help. ty

Comment: Why is regex your only option?

Comment: It is an existing system that modifies the data file prior to hitting the actual parser. When it modifies (all via bash regex, pipe after pipe), it does not account for the use case above so it modifies 3 and 7 as if they are two separate columns. Changing everything would be at least two weeks of work

Comment: But why does your code solution *have to* be regex? Also `cat file | perl -pi -e....` makes no sense. First off, you cannot in-place edit an input stream with `-i`, that is for files. Using cat is not necessary, you can just give the file name as argument to Perl. I assume you don't know what `-i` does, so remove that before,

Comment: It is an existing system that has been in use for more than 15 years. It does stuff before and after. I just cut the stuff here that is relevant.

Comment: I think what you mean is that you can pipe the data through a Perl process, and you *think* that that means only regexes can be used, and not other Perl code. There are many other things you can do in Perl besides using regexes.

Comment: Nope thats is not what I think and yes there are many things one can do with perl beside using regex. However, I am looking for a regex or a bash based solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it must be a regex here is a simpler one

```
perl -wpe's/("[^"]+")/ $1 =~ s{\|}{,}gr /eg' file
```

Not bullet-proof but it should work for the shown use case.<sup>†</sup>

Explanation.  With `/e` modifier the replacement side is evaluated as code. There, a regex runs on `$1` under `/r` so that the original (`$1`) is unchanged; `$N` are read-only and so we can't change `$1` and thus couldn't run a "normal" `s///` on it.  With this modifier the changed string is returned, or the original if there were no changes. Just as ordered.

Once it's tested well enough add `-i` to change the input file "in-place" if wanted.

---

I must add, I see no reason that at least this part of the job can't be done using a CSV parser...

---

Thanks to ikegami for an improved version

```
perl -wpe's/"[^"]+"/ $& =~ tr{|}{,}r /eg' file
```

It's simpler, with no need to capture, and `tr` is faster

---

<sup>†</sup> Tested with strings like in the question, extended only as far as this

```
con|"F, N"|12|10/21|"3|7"||Yes|"2||4|12"|"a|b"|No|""|end|
```

Comment: Re "*Not bullet-proof*", The only thing this doesn't handle is line feeds in a field. So yeah, works great. It takes advantage of the fact that the field must necessarily be quoted. If tere are any escaped quotes (`"...""..."`), the field will be treated as two fields, which is perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use [a CSV parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS), not regular expressions:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, sep_char => "|"});

while (my $row = $csv->getline(*ARGV)) {
    @$row = map { tr/|/,/r } @$row;
    $csv->say(*STDOUT, $row);
}
```

example:

```bash
$ perl demo.pl input.txt
continuer|"First, Name"|123|12412|10/21/2020|3,7||Yes|No|No|
```

More verbose, but also more robust and a lot easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot install modules, [`Text::ParseWords`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text::ParseWords) is a core module you can try. It can split a string and handle quoted delimiters.

```
use Text::ParseWords;

my $q = q(continuer|"First, Name"|123|12412|10/21/2020|"3|7"||Yes|No|No|);
print join "|", map { tr/|/,/; $_ } quotewords('\|', 1, $q);
```

As a one-liner, it would be:

```
perl -MText::ParseWords -pe'$_ = join "|", map { tr/|/,/; $_ } quotewords('\|', 1, $_);' yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You said `Update 2: Actually, I can use a bash based solution as well.` and while this script isn't bash you could call it from bash (or any other shell) which I assume is what you really mean by "bash based" so - this will work using any awk in any shell in every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/\|/,",",$i)} 1' file
continuer|"First, Name"|123|12412|10/21/2020|"3,7"||Yes|No|No|
```

Imagine yourself having to debug or enhance the clear, simple loop above above vs the regexp incantation you posted in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73450114/1745001):

```
's/(?:(?<=")|\G(?!^))(\s*[^"|\s]+(?:\s+[^"|\s]+)*)\s*\|\s*(?=[^"]*")/$1,/g'
```

Remember - [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

I'm sure you could do what I'm doing with awk above natively in perl instead if you're trying to modify a perl script to add this functionality.

Comment: This answer summarizes pretty much how I feel about this. Well put.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use Text::CSV_XS.

```bash
perl -MText::CSV_XS=csv -e'
   csv
      in       => \*ARGV,
      sep_char => "|",
      on_in    => sub { tr/|/,/ for @{ $_[1] } };
'
```

You can provide the file name as an argument or provide the data via STDIN.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am going to wait for a non module requiring solution if I can get one. I dont have this module installed atm. I will install and try if I have to. Appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

This is working right now

```
's/(?:(?<=")|\G(?!^))(\s*[^"|\s]+(?:\s+[^"|\s]+)*)\s*\|\s*(?=[^"]*")/$1,/g'
```

Credit goes to my boss at work

Thanks everyone for looking.

I hope some of you realize that some projects require certain ways and complicating an already very complicated pre existing structure is not always an option at work. I knew there would be a one liner for this, do not hate because you did not like that.

Comment: Please take this as a constructive observation as intended but maybe it's choosing to adopt unnecessarily complicated approaches like this that's caused your existing code to be, as you describe, `an already very complicated pre existing structure`. Even complicated problems don't require complicated solutions and in this case your problem is very simple.

Comment: You should not mistake experienced people disagreeing with you for hate.